# Is there a way to change the syntax color for the directory paths in the "Find results" tab in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext4

So when you search for a word in the whole project inside sublime text it opens a tab with a bunch of text containing the results of the search. Having all that text in the same color is a bit confusing for me so i want to know if there is a way to change at least the syntax color for the paths to the file that containts the similarity.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly, syntax highlighting in Sublime is controlled by [language syntax definition](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/syntax.html) files that use a
regex-based approach to assign [scopes](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/scope_naming.html) to different regions of text. [Color scheme](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/color_schemes.html) files then assign colors and font decorations (bold, italic, etc.) to the foregrounds and backgrounds of one or more scopes.

There are only a few scopes that color schemes can address in Find in Files:

- the base scope `text.find-in-files`
- `entity.name.filename.find-in-files`, which highlights the filename
- `constant.other.find-in-files`, which highlights lines beginning with `ERROR`
- `constant.numeric.line-number.find-in-files`, which highlights the line number of lines surrounding the result
- `constant.numeric.line-number.match.find-in-files`, which highlights the line number containing the match

The following basic rules will give you green filenames and underlined bold yellow matching line numbers

```json
    {
        "name": "Find In Files: filename",
        "scope": "entity.name.filename.find-in-files",
        "foreground": "#06FF05"
    },
    {
        "name": "Find In Files: Line Number - Match",
        "scope": "constant.numeric.line-number.match.find-in-files",
        "foreground": "#FFFF00",
        "font_style": "bold italic underline"
    },
```

Here is what that looks like using the [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme)<sup>*</sup>, which has a black background, other more general rules that cover the line numbers, and rules for outlining Find results in pink:

[image: Find in Files using Neon Color Scheme]

**<sup>*</sup>** Note: I am the color scheme's author.